# Determining the X, Y co-ordinates in sprite sheets

Tags: android, cocos2d

I am new to Android COCOS2D and developing a simple game to start with. I am developing a game for kids in which the kids shall spell out the names of the fruits they select. I have developed the sprite sheet consisting of pictures of several fruits. Kindly tell me how will the fruit on which the kid taps will get selected. How are the x and y co-ordinates in the sprite sheet determined??

I shall be thankful in case anyone can help me out with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your spritesheet and how you'd like to refer to each sprite.

**Horizontal Strip, Evenly Spaced**

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
```

Coordinates for tile corresponding to position `N`:

```
X = N * TileWidth
Y = 0
```

**Grid, Evenly Spaced, Single Index**

```
[0][1][2]
[3][4][5]
[6][7][8]
```

Coordinates for tile corresponding to position `N`:

```
X = (N % Cols) * TileWidth
Y = floor(N / Cols) * TileHeight
```

In this example `Cols` equals 3.

**Grid, Evenly Spaced, Double Index**

```
[0,0][1,0][2,0]
[0,1][1,1][2,1]
[0,2][1,2][2,2]
```

Coordinates for tile corresponding to position `NX` and `NY`:

```
X = NX * TileWidth
Y = NY * TileHeight
```

**Irregular Sprite Sheet**

Store rectangle regions of each sprite in a seperate file. E.g.

```
0 0 30 60      // First sprite at (0,0) with size (30,60)
30 0 100 60    // Second sprite at (30,0) with size (100,60)
0 60 130 60    // Third sprite at (0,60) with size (130,60)
```

Comment: Please explain the variable "N" denotes what..??
"N" is coordinates of tile or number of tile..??
Thanks

Comment: Number of tile, in the order specified on the "diagrams".